# Still Image using AVCaptureDevice with overlay image

Tags: iphone, avcapturesession

I am developing an iPhone app in which I am capturing the live video.

I have added the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to the self.view.layer as sublayer.
[self.view.layer addSublayer: self.prevLayer];

On the same self.view I have added an image as subview.
[self.view addSubView:image];

Now what I want is to capture an image from the live video but the image should also come into that picture as it looks on the screen.
I have tried to take the screen shot but it capture only the image and not the live video image.
Can any body please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi this will help you as it works for me

```
- (void)didTakePicture:(UIImage *)picture
{
    UIImage *frm = self.overlayViewController.imgOverlay.image;
    NSLog(@"width %f height %f",picture.size.width,picture.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(picture.size);
    [picture drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
    [frm drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, picture.size.width, picture.size.height)];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSLog(@"view %@",viewImage.debugDescription);
    [self.capturedImages addObject:viewImage];
}
```